# Scala: Writing type safe library for REST clients

Tags: scala, type-level-computation

Ive been reading about type level programming scala and have an idea which I would like to implement but have no luck on how to proceed with it. Basically I want a type safe library for REST clients. Typically REST API are string based and there is always a problem of having a typo or malformed API's. Basically I wan't to have something like this

`google / searchapi / search ? query("type safe library")`

`google / cloudapi / ml / classify ? body(binary_img)`

where google might be a class with a '/' method that accepts its subresources. then search will be a subresource that has a query method

Similarly google can have another subresource cloudapi that then takes another subresource ml and so on

This is just an idea. Is this even theoretically possible ? If so, any heads up to what I should be looking for ?

Comment: With a swagger file, and some code generation, not an issue.

Comment: I am not sure I understand what the benefit of this would be as opposed to something traditional like `googleClient.search("type safe library")`. If I had to choose, I'd actually prefer the latter form, because it doesn't force the caller to know that the implementation behind the call is using REST api, as opposed to, perhaps, a binary remote call, or a local implementation.

Comment: Have a look at akka http. It does something similar.